# Redirect with a complex QUERYSTRING

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm moving a CRM from Joomla to Wordpress and as a part of the process I wanted to set up some redirects for a set of existing pages. The current URLs are kind of long: baseurl.com/sub_dir/index.php/component/civicrm/?task=civicrm/pcp/info&reset=1&id=XX

I've found several posts explaining query string redirects but in all of them their variable is right after the ".php?". As you can see mine is not. I've tried the following (and a few similar variants) to no avail:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} task=civicrm/pcp/info&reset=1&id=20$
RewriteRule ^sub_dir/index\.php/component/civicrm/$ /path-to-new-location/? [L,R=301]
```

Eventually, I do want to write it with variables (as we have several hundred PCPs but I wanted to get something working first.) Any ideas?

Comment: This looks fine. Just make sure to keep this as very first rule.

Comment: Hmm, no dice still. I'm wondering if the rest of the Joomla htaccess file is messing things up. I will continue to test and post again!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for multiple URLss

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^task(.*)
RewriteRule ^sub_dir/index\.php/component/civicrm/$ /path-to-new-location/? [L,R=301]
```